# JavaQuartz Job persistence

Tags: java, struts2, quartz-scheduler

I am not much familiar with Java Quartz, we just used a test job thats scheduled daily. For our Struts2 webapplication, we want to run a few daily jobs that are scheduled at different times of the day. The jobs should be in persistence state such that even if the jobs fails due to server down/application failed, they should re-execute later when server is up. Also can i store the status/results of the jobs in DB, so as to monitor the jobs. Any suggestions would be helpful.

--
Thanks

Comment: I believe, Quartz has all these features. It can certainly use a persistent job store.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whatever you have mentioned is possible in Quartz scheduler and there is already a feature with triggers which we generally call `Misfire Instructions`this is what doc say about it

> Another important property of a Trigger is its "misfire instruction". A misfire occurs if a persistent trigger "misses" its firing time because of the scheduler being shutdown, or because there are no available threads in Quartz's thread pool for executing the job. The different trigger types have different misfire instructions available to them. By default they use a 'smart policy' instruction - which has dynamic behavior based on trigger type and configuration. When the scheduler starts, it searches for any persistent triggers that have misfired, and it then updates each of them based on their individually configured misfire instructions. When you start using Quartz in your own projects, you should make yourself familiar with the misfire instructions that are defined on the given trigger types, and explained in their JavaDoc. More specific information about misfire instructions will be given within the tutorial lessons specific to each trigger type.

Regarding Job persistence Quartz comes with few build in mechanism and all you need to set JobStore as `JDBCJobStore`

I suggest you to go with [Quartz scheduler document](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/) its quite easy and have lots of tutorial and examples to start with.

If you are not using Spring in your application there is no need to add extra level of abstraction and dependencies.

Comment: After going through the docs, i found jobStore are responsible for keeping track of all the "work data" that you give to the scheduler: jobs, triggers, calendars, etc. Is it possible to also store the Job state in jobStore, i.e, the result/execution status..

Comment: Any particular Lesson no. in the documentation where i can find details on retrieving the jobs state of a scheduler job.

Comment: In order to register Quartz in our webapplication we have to add quartz-service.xml. But in which location to add this exactly in struts2 project, inside  src or in web-inf.

Comment: you can even use property file and can pass the name to the Quartz filter

Comment: This will give you an idea what to do and how to do http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/ServletInitScheduler

Comment: I applied all the changes required in web.xml as per the quartz-2 cookbook, but getting - Quartz Scheduler failed to initialize: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery.  more details @ https://gist.github.com/d5b84145f4b5e06f8513

Comment: as per the error/exception its unable to find `SimpleJob` class. I suggest you to open a new question with all relevant details what you have done and where u facing this issue

Answer (score 2):

You can use Quartz combined with [Sprig batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/).

The former provides API for managing various flows (as complex as you need), persistent storage of job state and api for monitoring and re-running jobs according to their execution status.
Another handy library is [Spring Batch admin](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch-admin/reference/reference.pdf). It has web console and 5 minutes guide.

Quartz is used as scheduler job state persistence is handled by Spring batch.. It can run as standalone java application and also in web/application container (for me Tomcat was enough).

Good luck!

Comment: For using the Spring Batch Admin, do i need to use Springs framework in my existing Struts2 web-app

Answer (score 1):

We have `Job stores` api in Java Quartz. This will persist data in the databases about the information of the Job. So i guess this will help you. You can check [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-quartz/) to get an idea about code and DB structure.