# How to keep scheduled job in Quartz after restart?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have created a scheduled job with Quartz that will run every minute. 
The job is created from following guide: http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/11/17/quartz.net-writing-your-first-hello-world-job.aspx

The problem is that when the service is stopped and restarted the job is no longer in the scheduler.

How do I keep the scheduled job in the list?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You must use quartz persistance -- usually the config is stored in a db table.  Here is a post with useful links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186201/javaquartz-job-persistence

Comment: I'm not familiar with Quartz at all, but is it loaded in memory?  Then you'd need to store your jobs to database or disk as config file(s).

Comment: Thank you both for helping. I added my job in the quartz_jobs.xml file and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David F and bland helped me find the answer.
I added my job in the XML file named quartz_jobs.xml.

```xml
<job>
    <name>MyJob</name>
    <group>MyGroup</group>
    <description>Job for MyJob</description>
    <job-type>ScheduledDownloader.DownloadJob, ScheduledDownloader</job-type>
    <durable>true</durable>
    <recover>false</recover>
</job>

<trigger>
    <cron>
        <name>MyJob</name>
        <group>MyGroup</group>
        <description>Cron trigger for MyJob</description>
        <job-name>MyJob</job-name>
        <job-group>MyGroup</job-group>
        <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
        <cron-expression>0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *</cron-expression>
    </cron>
</trigger>
```

Thanks again for the speedy help, it sure made my day.

Comment: Makes sense, but if I'd like jobs scheduled dynamically, as the result of some other job, or user request and the system restarts, this would be somewhat less useful. Does anybody know how to make calls to scheduleJob durable through restart? It also begs the question about multiple jvm instances coordinating that work. Do they both see the jobs? It seems they do in my tests, but I can't figure out why they get lost after I recycle a box.