# Save and restart the thread pool after server shutdown

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, runnable, threadpoolexecutor

My application have multiple threads. In case server goes down or get restarted, I want to execute ONLY those threads which were not executed. For example in the snippet below: consider if server goes down after thread number 1,4,2 are executed. The applicaiton should execute 2,3 and 5 threads after server restarts.

The task of threads are ATOMIC in nature. Either all of it gets done or nothing happens. So I have to somehow save the sate of every thread already executed. How can I do that?

```
class HugeJob implements Runnable {
int param;
 public HugeJob(int var) {
       this.param = var;
   }

   public void run() {
       //This is an ATOMIC task i.e. either all gets done or nothing
       //Each thread task takes ~20 minute. Heavy I/O and network operations
       //I have to make sure no thread executes more than once even if server is restarted
       System.out.println(this.param);
   }
}

public class ThreadSample {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    for(int i =0; i<5;i++)
      {
        HugeJob obj = new HugeJob(i);
        new Thread(obj).start();
      }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

***Edit***
Can I use Quartz to achieve this? Is it a good idea to create each and every thread a s a separate job and persist it using Quartz? Here is a related link: [JavaQuartz Job persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186201/javaquartz-job-persistence)

Comment: Is there a finite number of parameters that can uniquely describe your thread?  Do you have a database to use?

Comment: Yes, There is a database to use and also an unique ID for every task. Are you suggesting that I should query DB on server start up?

Comment: You need a persistent thread pool with the ability to re-run a particular thread if it didn't finish.  If your threads are very similar with just some parameter difference, then you can keep these parameters in the database.  The problem of a split second described below still remains.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your requirements are impossible as this is a variant of the Byzantine generals problem, which is provably unsolvable. The thread being done is analogous to one of the generals attacking The recording needed to ensure the thread does not run again is analogous to the other general attacking. Your requirement is thus analogous to a requirement that either both generals attack or neither does is thus impossible to meet.

You cannot avoid the following basic problem.

1. The thread finishes.
2. You record that the thread finished such that you don't do the work again.

What if the system shuts down after 1 but before 2?

You need to rethink the problem and your requirements. The oversimplified version you've presented cannot be solved as asked.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @david I agreed the sample code is not exactly what I have in my app. Will update this thread if I find some solution or rework...

Answer (score 0):

I solve it this problem in a little complex way

- I use Callable Interface so that I can keep track of my “Thread”
- Add a ShutdownHook [1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29)

Part 1: Create the callable object

```
Set<Future<Boolean>> set = new HashSet<Future<Boolean>>();
```

public HttpServer server =null;
   public HttpContext hc = null;

```
public void myServerInitiator() throws IOException {
    server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);
    hc = server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
    // create all the thread and start it here
    for(int i =0; i<5;i++)
       Callable<Boolean> callable = new MyDelegator ();
       Future<Boolean> future = pool.submit(callable);
       set.add(future);
    }
    ........
}
```

Part 2: Add the hook

```
public void myServerStop() throws IOException {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    rt.addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
          public void run() {
              // In real life this might close a Connection or something.
              System.out.println("Running shutdown hook and closing all connection");
              if(server != null) {
                  server.removeContext(hc);
                  server.stop(1);                     
              }
              // get all the "thread object" and do whatever you want based on the state
           for (Future<Boolean> future : set) {

             }
          });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dipankaj Can you please look at the edit in my original post and suggest if I can use Quarz to achieve this?

Comment: yes you can. But please read http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-you-shouldnt-use-quartz